# IFrame Editor IE encoding

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, encoding, editor

My page have meta tag for UTF-8,

I created an iframe editor with;

```
document.getElementById('myeditor').contentWindow.document.designMode="on";
document.getElementById('myeditor').contentWindow.document.close();
```

and getting the value of this iframe with;

```
$('#myeditor').contents().find('body').html() or ('#myeditor').contents().find('body').text()
```

both worked in chrome, firefox but IE return value has different encoding

the entered text(original) = "çöşiğüişçö" (or something similar)

database value when i get from chrome =  `Ã§Ã¶iÅŸÃ§Ã¶iÅŸÃ¼ÄŸ Ã§Ã¶iÅŸÃ¼ÄŸiÅŸÃ§Ã¶iÅŸÃ¼ÄŸ Ã§Ã¶ (This is ok for me.)`

database value when i get from IE = `çöiþçöiþüðiþçöiþüðiþçöiþüðþö`

i tried to change meta in the iframe but nothing works. when i look at the code in ie webtool, iframe has a meta tag which is " meta name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 9.00.8112.16434" "

Please help me.

(IE9)

Answer (score 0):

They text you're entering is not likely in UTF-8 format.

Comment: how should i find what the text encoding is and change it to utf-8.

Comment: Use notepad++ and select ENCODING on the main menu. Then you can paste it from there.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">      and goes....